# C++ No compatible standard constructor found

Tags: c++, class, vector, constructor

I created the following class in a header file:

```
class clsJoinFeeder
{
public:
    vector<vector<float>>&Floats;
    vector<vector<unsigned char>>&UnsignedChars;
};
```

I am not yet using this class at all (to avoid any additional mistakes).

The compiler tells me "No compatible constructor found".

Why is the compiler telling me that? I don't want to use a constructor. My class is only meant for holding these values.

Comment: small note: on some compilers (like Sun CC), the `>>` is interpreted as a bit shift. So you need to put a space in between, like `> >`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class does not hold any data values, it holds references to (external) containers with data values. Referenced *must* be initialized with something, because after object construction their pointee can not be changed (and if there is no pointee given in constructor, they become useless).

If you want a class *holding* data, you probably should define it without using references:

```
class clsJoinFeeder
{
public:
    vector<vector<float> > Floats;
    vector<vector<unsigned char> > UnsignedChars;
};
```

If you need references, you must define constructor initializing them:

```
class clsJoinFeeder
{
public:
    vector<vector<float> > &Floats;
    vector<vector<unsigned char> > &UnsignedChars;

    clsJoinFeeder(         
        vector<vector<float> > &Floats0,
        vector<vector<unsigned char> > &UnsignedChars0
    ) : Floats(Floats0), UnsignedChars(UnsignedChars0) 
    { /*or maybe some code here*/ }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess you are right. I think my entire construct is not nice. I will try to change that.

Comment: I know it is a hilarious question, but what is the difference if I use references or not? When I don't use references, does this mean that the entire <vector<vector<float>> is copied when I access one values of it, for example like this? unsigned char btIndex=this->UnsignedChars[10][100];

Comment: @tmighty Reference does not hold data itself, it is like pointer, more specifically, it is like constant pointer that is "already dereferenced by itself" - let us have `char * const p = &x;` and `char &r = x;` than `r` and `(*p)` are almost the same and are interchangable in most code constructs. Vectors, like other objects, are copied when you assign them (themselves, not their fields) or pass them by value. With `this->UnsignedChars[10][100]` you are calling twice access method `operator []` of two vector objects (`UnsignedChars` and its 10th element), this will never copy any of them.

Comment: And, by the way, vector's method `operator []` returns you a *reference* to the element beeing accessed, not a copy of it. By doing so, it do not only skip redundant copy construction, but gives you possibility to *change directly* referenced element, residing inside the vector.

Comment: Vectors, like other objects, are copied when you assign them (themselves, not their fields) or pass them by value **or return then by value** (!)

Answer (score 0):

The class contains two references to vectors. But to which vectors? To create an instance of that class you need a way to initialize the references to point to some real objects.

Since you didn't declare a constructor yourself, the compiler tries to generate a default constructor. This fails, since it doesn't know how to initialize the references.